# Change the .htaccess router, id to title

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with PHP.
My htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=news&id=$1

#Redirecciones
#Redirect 301 / /index.php

# Quickregister Rules
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Right now to access the news in this case the route would be this:

```
http://localhost/news/3
```

And I want to change it to access some as follows

```
http://localhost/news/mi-noticia-nueva
http://localhost/news/mi-noticia-nueva/3
```

I have tried the following rewritrule without success:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+/[\w-]+)$ index.php?url=news?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?url=news&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ index.php?url=news&name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: But there is no `id` in `/news/mi-noticia-nueva`?

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not sure if it's possible to remove the id completely, so I put two options. Either of the two examples I gave would work for me.

Comment: You _can_ remove the ID - but then you won't have it available any more as criterion for record selection in your news database. So that part of your script would then have to be modified accordingly, so that it now goes and looks up the record via that news name you passed instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(news)/(?:.*/)?(\d+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will support there URIs:

```bash
/news/mi-noticia-nueva/3
/news/3
```

Pattern used is:

- `^`: Start
- `(news)`: Match and group `news`
- `/`: Match a `/`
- `(?:.*/)?`: Match any test followed by a `/`. This is optional match
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #2
- `/?$`: Match optional `/` before end